# The Podfile does not contain any dependencies

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, swift3

Cocoapod 1.1.1

Xcode 8.1 beta

Want to add Firebase/Core pod

Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'AddPodAdMob' do
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase/Core'
end
end
```

Without adding source it was not creating `.xcworkspace` file.

Now showing this after pod install command.

```
Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total pods installed.

[!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.
```

Any help please...